# android: different images copied to same file name shows always first image

Tags: android, image, caching

I copy an image from a server to a local file with constant file name. Then I show the image using

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(constantFileName), mime);
startActivity(intent);
```

So far, this works. But then I copy another image to the same local file and want to show it: instead of the new image, the old one is shown - this looks like file name dependent caching. How can I prevent this caching?

Comment: Are you sure that your code deletes the old file before it generates the new one? Where do you put that file?

Comment: the old file is being overwritten and is located anywhere on the andoid file system.

Comment: as soon as I rename the file, the correct image is shown - so I know that the overwriting works

Comment: when I rename it back, the wrong image is shown again - without changing the file contents